# Tooltip doesn't appear on path gaps

Tags: c#, wpf, path, tooltip

I have a special path that contains several filled parts with gaps between them, and I want a tooltip to appear above it. I want the tooltip to appear on the gaps as well, but it only appears on the filled parts. I've tried to put the path inside a canvas with a transparent background but it doesn't help.

This is my xaml:

```
<Canvas  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="appbar_connection_quality_veryhigh" Width="76" Height="31" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0" Background="Transparent" ToolTip="Hi!!!">
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="0.4"/>
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    <Path Width="38" Height="38" Canvas.Left="19" Canvas.Top="19" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{DynamicResource SignalStrength5Brush}" Data="F1 M 41,35L 41,57L 35,57L 35,35L 41,35 Z M 33,44L 33,57L 27,57L 27,44L 33,44 Z M 19,57L 19,51L 25,51L 25,57L 19,57 Z M 57,19L 57,57L 51,57L 51,19L 57,19 Z M 49,27L 49,57L 43,57L 43,27L 49,27 Z "/>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct.

Just set `Height="60"` for Canvas instead of 31 and it should work.